# MySQL on iscsi drive CentOS7 wont start on boot

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, mariadb, open-iscsi

I configured Mariadb on CentOS 7 to run on iscsi drive mounted on /mnt/iscsi, but it wont start on boot with following error (it can be started manually):

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-02-10 09:54:50 MSK; 51s ago
Process: 1283 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 10 09:54:32 localhost systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Feb 10 09:54:50 localhost mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1283]: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/iscsi/mysql_databases/��...enied
Feb 10 09:54:50 localhost systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 10 09:54:50 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Feb 10 09:54:50 localhost systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

journalctl erros:

```
journalctl _PID=1283
 -- Logs begin at Tue 2015-02-10 11:39:22 MSK, end at Tue 2015-02-10 11:50:01 MSK. --
 Feb 10 11:44:09 localhost mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1264]: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/iscsi/mysql_databases/’: Permissio
```

Journalctl by executable

```
journalctl /usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir
 -- Logs begin at Tue 2015-02-10 11:39:22 MSK, end at Tue 2015-02-10 12:05:51 MSK. --
 Feb 10 11:44:09 localhost mariadb-prepare-db-dir[1264]: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/iscsi/mysql_databases/’: Permissio
```

There is no errors in "/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log"
So, I tried to modify boot order:

```
systemctl list-dependencies --before mariadb
mariadb.service
├─iscsi.service
├─iscsid.service
├─iscsid.socket
├─mnt-iscsi.mount
├─multi-user.target
│ ├─systemd-readahead-done.service
│ ├─systemd-readahead-done.timer
│ ├─systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
│ └─graphical.target
│   └─systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
└─shutdown.target
  ├─systemd-reboot.service
  └─final.target
    └─systemd-reboot.service
```

it didn't help :(

permissions:

```
 ls -aZ /mnt
     drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:file_t:s0 iscsi

 ls -aZ /mnt/iscsi/
     drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql_databases

 ls -aZ /mnt/iscsi/mysql_databases
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 ibdata1
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 ib_logfile0
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 ib_logfile1
     drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql-bin.000001
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql-bin.index
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql-error.log
     -rw-rw----. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql-slow.log
     drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 performance_schema
     drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 test
```

SELinux is in permissive mode.

Comment: OK, what are the permissions on `/mnt/iscsi`? And `/mnt`?

Comment: Updated first post with this information

Answer (score 1):

From the information provided

> ...mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mnt/iscsi/mysql_databases/��...enied

This looks like you have some sort of a permission/ownership/SELinux context issue.

You should review the permissions, ownerships and SElinux context of the /mnt/iscsi tree and take appropriate action.

Comment: SELinux in permissive mode. Permissions are correct.
Mariadb perfectly starts with 'systemctl start mariadb' after system boots as i mentioned it my first post

Comment: What extra information is available when you use joutnalctl ?

Comment: Same error as above in journalctl, nothing more.

Comment: There should be more because it should not be elided.

Comment: Nothing more. Or I am trying to get in a wrong way.